spring batch tasklet to write a file reexecute the whole job
I implemented a spring batch tasklet that

reads two files
merges both txt files into a single String list,
writes the list content to a file under resource folder

The issue is that the step 3 (the write function), when activated, the whole job is reexcuted indefinitely, no file is created (list content) and no exception is thrown ?
The issue disappears when the step 3 is commented
any ideas for improvements are welcome
